# How to pass multiple objects into a single handlebars page/ template

Tags: mysql, node.js, handlebars.js

I have two mysql queries , each returning the last record entered for each value "aboutUsDiv1" and "aboutUsDiv2" in a column called "ElementId".

I have one handlebars template where I would like to display both objects (in separate divs) return from my queries.

How can I pass both objects into my handlebars template and display them in separate divs? Is that possible?

**ContentUpdate.js**

```
exports.showAboutUs1 = function(req,res)
{
 req.getConnection(function(err, connection){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM `editablecontent` WHERE ElementId = "AboutUsDiv1" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1  ',[], function(err, result){
   return res.render('AboutUs', {
    data1: result,
    admin: req.session.admin,
    user: req.session.user
 });
console.log(data);
   });
  });
};

exports.showAboutUs2 = function(req,res)
{
  req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM `editablecontent` WHERE ElementId = "AboutUsDiv2" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1  ',[], function(err, result){
   return res.render('AboutUs', {
    data2: result,
    admin: req.session.admin,
    user: req.session.user
  });
 console.log(result);
    });
   });
 };
```

**AboutUs.handlebars**

```
      <div class="row"> 
        <div>
          {{#data1 }}
           <div id="AboutUsDiv1" >
              <h3 class="Title">{{Title}}</h3>
              <p class="text">  {{Text}}</p>                      
            </div>
           {{/data1 }}
         </div>
       </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="row">       
         <div>
          {{#data2}}
            <div id="AboutUsDiv2" >
               <h3 class="Title">{{Title}}</h3>
               <p class="text">{{Text}}</p>                       
            </div>
           {{/data2}}
          </div>
    </div>
```

**app.js**

```
var contentUpdate = require("./functions/ContentUpdate");
...
app.get('/aboutUs', function(req,res){
  contentUpdate.showAboutUs1;
  contentUpdate.showAboutUs2;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this.

```
 exports.showAboutUs1 = function (req, res) {
  req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `editablecontent` WHERE ElementId = "AboutUsDiv1" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1  ', [], function (err, result1) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM `editablecontent` WHERE ElementId = "AboutUsDiv2" ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1  ', [], function (err, result2) {
            return res.render('AboutUs', {
                data1: result1,
                data2: result2,
                admin: req.session.admin,
                user: req.session.user
            });
            console.log(result1);
            console.log(result2);
        });
    });
 });
};
```

**app.js**

```
var contentUpdate = require("./functions/ContentUpdate");
...
app.get('/aboutUs', function(req,res){
contentUpdate.showAboutUs1;
});
```

Comment: I landed up solving the problem, in the exact same way you answered the question, but thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble sending 2 objects of a Mongo query to the same handlebar view, following the logic of the comment above I can resolve the problem

My code that´s work:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {

Categorie.find(  function(err, categorie){
Post.find( function(err, post){
res.render('Painel_principal',{
  savedCategorie: categorie,
  savedPosts: post 
   })
  })
})
```

hbs view:

```
    <a class="button" href="/admin/categories">Categorias</a>


    {{!-- Block for a new post --}}
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
          <form action="/admin/posts/new" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content"placeholder="O que há de novo?" rows="3" required></textarea> 
            </div>
            <select class="custom-select" name="categorie" id="categorie" >
              <option selected>Selecione uma categoria</option>
              {{#if savedCategorie}}
                  {{#each savedCategorie}}
                  <option value="{{_id}}">{{nome}}</option>
                  {{/each}}
              {{else}}
                  <option value="0">Sem categorias</option>
              {{/if}}

            </select>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-1">Postar</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    {{!-- Listing posts --}}

    <div class="card mt-5 post">
      {{#if savedPosts}}
          {{#each savedPosts}}
                <div class="card-body">
                  <img src="img/igor.jpg" class="postProfilerPic" width="32px">
                  <small class="">Igor b.s</small>
                  <small class="float-right categorie">#categoreiName</small>
                  <p>
                    {{content}}
                  </p>
                  <small class="float-right postDate">Publicado em:{{date}}</small>
                </div>
          {{/each}}
      {{else}}
          <div class="card-body">
            Nenhum post
          </div>
      {{/if}}

    </div>
```